# admob banner not showing in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, admob

hello AdMob banner ads not showing up any more after I add ScrollView I don't know why I tried many time but nothing 
before added ScrollView is was working well

I have tried  many methods to put in bottom the layout but not working with me

plz if you can help me I want to I want to place the ad on the bottom I have a LinearLayout. When I do it never shows up

```
    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <RelativeLayout
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15.0dip">

                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="17.0sp"
                        android:textColor="#ff000000"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Extreme power saving mode" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/setSwitch1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: full code https://pastebin.com/yfCNF7bP

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your code. Wrap your layout in relative. Layout below and above only works in relative not in linear, and remove the two linear layout below that is wrapping the adView.

This should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="#fff1f1f1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



<Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Toolbar>

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mytoolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        <RelativeLayout
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_margin="15.0dip">

                <TextView
                        android:textSize="17.0sp"
                        android:textColor="#ff000000"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Extreme power saving mode" />
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
                        android:text="The disadvantage is that the playback progress will be lost."
                        android:ems="11" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/setSwitch1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15.0dip">
                <TextView android:textSize="17.0sp"
                          android:textColor="#ff000000"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="Desktop control playback" />
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
                        android:text="Quickly click or swipe three times" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Switch android:id="@+id/setSwitch2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout

                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">

            <TextView
                    android:textSize="17.0sp"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15.0dip"
                    android:text="Sound" />

            <Switch

                    android:id="@+id/setSwitch3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/setRelativeLayout1"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">

            <LinearLayout

                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15.0dip">

                <TextView
                        android:textSize="17.0sp"
                        android:textColor="#ff000000"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Compatibility mode" />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/moreTextView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
                        android:text="MIUI8 set as lock screen wallpaper" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/setRelativeLayout2"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">

            <TextView
                    android:textSize="17.0sp"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15.0dip"
                    android:text="Get Starry Sky Wallpaper" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlRate"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">
            <TextView android:textSize="17.0sp"
                      android:textColor="#ff000000"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_margin="15.0dip"
                      android:text="rate us " />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/setRelativeLayout3"
                        android:background="#ffffffff"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">
            <TextView android:textSize="17.0sp"
                      android:textColor="#ff000000"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_margin="15.0dip"
                      android:text="Close wallpaper" />
        </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```